# How to update salesforce custom object (Customer__c) OptIn field value from Marketing cloud (Customer DE) OptIn attribute value using AMP script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, ssjs, cloudpage

I have a scenario, 1 DE (Customer DE with SubscriberKey, OptIn, Status, OptInDate attributes) with some records. I want to update the salesforce Customer__c object records OptIn (Yes/No) if SubscriberKey is matching from MC using AMPScript.

I have tried UpdateSingleSalesforceObject method but results are getting empty. below is the code which i tried.

```ampscript
%%[
var @result
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Customer__c', @SubscriberKey,'Mobile_Number__c', @MobileNumber,'Promo_Pref__c',@SMSOptIn)
]%%
```

Also considering this is for multiple records update.

Comment: Hey, Venkat. This community is super helpful, but please don't presume we'll write code for you given a list of requirements.  Please try writing this yourself and update your question to include your attempt, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Sure Adam, thanks for your suggestion. I just updated my code in the query. I am new to AMP script as i am getting confusion for mapping variables (@variables). Are these variables from DEs or Data Views?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks as it should [according to the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/updatesinglesalesforceobject.html). It should be possible to specify multiple additional fields and value pairs. I would wrap the code in an SSJS try-catch, double-check the IDs, and check integration user permissions to troubleshoot.

1. You should be getting a 0 or 1 from the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject, where 1 represents success and 0 failure. Since you get "empty," I would start by wrapping your AMPscript in an SSJS try-catch to understand better what is going on:

   ```
    <script runat="server">
      Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
      try{
    </script>

    %%[ your AMPscript block goes here  ]%%

    <script runat="server">
      } catch(e) {
        Write(Stringify(e));
      }
    </script>
   ```
2. It Looks like you are using a custom object for your contacts. Double-check that you have the correct ID for Customer__c as your Subscriber Key.
3. Make sure your integration user has write access to the custom object and the fields and that the format, e.g., the correct number of digits mobile phone number, is OK. Try running UpdateSingleSalesforceObject with just 1 parameter and a known Customer__c record ID.